# How to keep menu highlighted?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, highlight

I have a slight problem. Mostly because I'm still learning JQuery.

When a user clicks an item from the menu it is highlighted. So far so good. But, if the user enters another link inside the page he selected from the menu, the highlight is lost.

How can I keep the menu item highlighted until the user selects another option from said menu?

The Jquery code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sidemenu a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
</script>
```

In case it is needed the menu code, and the css for the example, here is the JFiddle demo (although it won't work there): http://jsfiddle.net/dptv0os6/3/

Comment: Did you refer http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/?

Comment: I don't get the idea something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/dptv0os6/11/

Comment: Nope. Although seeing the example, does that works with <li>?

Comment: Did I understand you right, that you have a menu link like "Business" and then sub menu links like the ones you mentioned in your Jfiddle? And then if you click on a subpage you want the main menu link to still be active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this easy code:

```
$('.sidemenu li').on('click', function () {
                $('li.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
```

Basically everytime you click on a li you add a class to it and delete the class from previews one:

your fddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/dptv0os6/12/

Comment: Btw.. if you don't want a "li" already higlighted, just delete the class "active" in the html and it will still works fine

Comment: This is working fine, except in my application. For some reason, if I add class to <li>, it isn't highlighted, but if I add it to <a>, the item is highlighted.

Comment: with this you add the class "active" to your "li". If you want to highlight the a element just use: .active a {background-color:#A0A0A0;/*or whatever else you want*/}. If still problems you may have a css with priority over those "a", so add !important to the .active a class property

Comment: It was a problem with my CSS code. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1):

If your pages are in another folder like /parent-page/sub-page, you can save the pathname in your url like so:

```
var pathname = document.location.pathname;
```

Then you simply do a match.

```
if(pathname.match(/parent-page/i){
   $('yourmenulink').addClass("selected");
}
```

For further understanding: You put your html files of the given parent page in a folder you like to. If you do that, you can access the folder name via the url with location.pathname.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by css .

```
.active{
background-color:red; // example
}
```